# How to send Email with attachment in angular using nodemialer?

Tags: node.js, express, angular6, nodemailer

My website careers page, User need to send their profile and then profile(doc or pdf) need to send as an attachment to the email on clicking submit button. Technologies I am using Angular6, NodeJs, Express, and Nodemailer to send the email.

Here is my peace of HTML code(careers.html),

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="sendData()" >
       <textarea [(ngModel)]="user.message"></textarea>
         <input type="file" (change)="userProfile($event)" >
          <small>Upload .docx or pdf file</small>
       <button >Submit</button>
   </form>
```

a bit of ts code (careers.ts),

```
   user = {
      message: '',
      fileContent :''
    };

     userProfile(event: any) {        
          if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = (event: any) => {
          this.user.fileContent = event.target.result;
              }
              reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
          }

     sendData() {   
          this.careersService.sendWithAttachment(this.user);
     }
```

here is service class(service.ts),

```
  sendWithAttachment(userData) {

    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/uploadfile", userData
    )
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("Sent Request is successful ", data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log("Error", error);
        }
      );
  }
```

finally js file (app.js)

```
var mailOptions = {
        from: '"User" <mail@gmail.com>', // sender address
        to: "mail@mail.com", // list of receivers
        subject: "Mail from Careers",
        text: text,
        html: html, // html body
        attachments: [  {  
            filename: 'profile.pdf',
            content: req.body.fileContent,
            contentType: 'application/pdf'
        }]
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
    });
```

Now I am able to receive email with attachement but that attachement is empty or corrupted. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload the file on the server, Maybe you can do it though [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) and then you can pass the server file path to the Nodemailer Function.

Here are some code snippet for your reference,

```
var express = require('express')
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/uploadfile', upload.single('profile'), function (req, res) {
    var mailOptions = {
        ....
        attachments: [{
            filename: req.file.filename,
            path: req.file.path
        }]
    };
    ...
})
```

Note : Attachment can be done in various methods in Nodemailer, Refer the [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/)